# Subview not loading, but not crashing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

So I've been struggling all day, trying to get a subview to show up on my app. I'm not getting any errors or crashes, but the subview just isn't showing up.

code that calls the subview from the main ViewController (calls when a button is tapped):

```
- (IBAction)SettingsButtonTapped:(id)sender {
  SettingsView *settings= [[SettingsView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
  //Thank you to Calman for fixing the init!
  [self.view addSubview:settings];
}
```

and here is the subview .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *username;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneNumber;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *BackButton;

@end
```

and the .m file:

```
#import "SettingsView.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation SettingsView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
      NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      NSString *name = [prefs stringForKey:@"name"];
      NSString *number = [prefs stringForKey:@"number"];
      username.tag=1;
      phoneNumber.tag=2;
      //if username is there
      if(name!=NULL)
      {
        username.text = name;
      }

      //if phone number is there
      if(number!=NULL)
      {
        phoneNumber.text=number;
      }

    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/
@synthesize username;
@synthesize phoneNumber;

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSString *data=textField.text;
    if(textField.tag==1){
    //username was edited
    [prefs setObject:data forKey:@"name"];
  }
  else if (textField.tag==2){
    //phone number was edited
    [prefs setObject:data forKey:@"number"];
  }
}


@end
```

If anyone knows or has any ideas what might be going wrong, I'd love to hear!

Comment: Can you move the initialization to a handmade viewWasLoaded() method and call it before adding it as subview? And use `self.username.text = ...`.

Comment: @ott-- could you explain that a little bit more? I don't quite understand what you're suggesting

Comment: try setting a background color and see if you see the colored rectangle shows up?

Comment: @rocky tried that, but unfortunately nothing came up. Thanks though!

Comment: So, i have gotten it to enter the .m file, but it will not display the contents of the .xib file

Comment: Are you using .xib/storyboard for the parent view that has autolayout enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a xib file, then you're using the wrong init method. You need to load the nib like this:

```
- (IBAction)SettingsButtonTapped:(id)sender {

  UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:nil];
  SettingsView *settings= [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0];
  [self.view addSubview:settings];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! That's what finally did it for me

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code that you're using to add the subvoew to the following:

```
- (IBAction)SettingsButtonTapped:(id)sender {
  SettingsView *settings= [[SettingsView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]; //Change the CGRect to your appropriate origin and size
  [self.view addSubview:settings];
}
```

What you are currently doing is to instantiate the view with no frame, so even though you add it, it's not visible. Additionally, none of your initialization code is actually being called when you call just init.

Comment: That was definitely a much needed change, but unfortunately there is still nothing coming up! Any other ideas?